# Generic value and type comparer with operators

Tags: c#, generics, compare

I have a business logic, base on the pre-defined condition (`OperatorType` and compare value), validate if it is true or false. The problem here is the value is "typed", and with operator (greater/less/equal etc).

If `ValueType` is Integer, then the value and compare value need to converted to `Integer` first, then base on `OperatorType`, do comparison.

I would like to know if I can have a general function, passing `CompareValue`, `Value`, `ValueType`, `OperatorType` and return true/false.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var compare1 = 3;
            var foo1 = new Foo { Value = "2", OperatorType = OperatorTypes.GreaterOrEqual, ValueType = ValueTypes.Long };
            //compare compare1 and foo1.Value, output should be false (2 < 3)

            var compare2 = true;
            var foo2 = new Foo { Value = "True", OperatorType = OperatorTypes.Equal, ValueType = ValueTypes.Bool };
            //compare compare2 and foo2.Value, output should be true (true = true)

            var compare3 = DateTime.Parse("2013-03-19 15:00");
            var foo3 = new Foo { Value = "2013-03-19 16:00", OperatorType = OperatorTypes.Less, ValueType = ValueTypes.Date };
            //compare compare3 and foo3.Value, output should be false (2013-03-19 16:00 < 2013-03-19 15:00)
        }
    }

    public enum OperatorTypes : uint
    {
        Equal = 1,
        Greater = 2,
        GreaterOrEqual = 3,
        Less = 4,
        LessOrEqual = 5
    }

    public enum ValueTypes : uint
    {
        None = 0,
        Integer = 1,
        Long = 2,
        Numeric = 3,
        Date = 4,
        Text = 5,
        Bool = 6
    }

    class Foo
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public ValueTypes ValueType { get; set; }
        public OperatorTypes OperatorType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question? To the **edit** Yes you can write such a function. What have you tried?

Comment: @sehe sorry, I updated my question. I would like to know if I can have a general function, passing CompareValue, Value, ValueType, OperatorType and return true/false.

Comment: @sehe, I tried with new Comparer<T> but it is a base class not implementation. I tried Convert.ChangeType based on ValueType but it still missed last step which is comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without further ado, to get you started:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        public static dynamic CompareVal(Foo logic)
        {
            switch(logic.ValueType)
            {
                case ValueTypes.Integer: return Convert.ToInt32(logic.Value);
                case ValueTypes.Long:    return Convert.ToInt64(logic.Value);
                case ValueTypes.Numeric: return Convert.ToDecimal(logic.Value);
                case ValueTypes.Date:    return Convert.ToDateTime(logic.Value);
                case ValueTypes.Text:    return logic.Value;
                case ValueTypes.Bool:    return Convert.ToBoolean(logic.Value);
            }
            throw new InvalidProgramException("Unsupported ValueType");
        }

        public static bool Evaluate(dynamic val, Foo logic)
        {
            dynamic cmpval = CompareVal(logic);

            switch(logic.OperatorType)
            {
                case OperatorTypes.Equal:          return val == cmpval;
                case OperatorTypes.Greater:        return val >  cmpval;
                case OperatorTypes.GreaterOrEqual: return val >= cmpval;
                case OperatorTypes.Less:           return val <  cmpval;
                case OperatorTypes.LessOrEqual:    return val <= cmpval;
            }

            return false;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //compare compare1 and foo1.Value, output should be false (2 < 3)
            Debug.Assert(false == Evaluate(3, new Foo 
                        { 
                            Value = "2", 
                            OperatorType = OperatorTypes.GreaterOrEqual, 
                            ValueType = ValueTypes.Long 
                        }));

            //compare compare2 and foo2.Value, output should be true (true = true)
            Debug.Assert(true == Evaluate(true, new Foo 
                        { 
                            Value = "True", 
                            OperatorType = OperatorTypes.Equal, 
                            ValueType = ValueTypes.Bool 
                        }));

            //compare compare3 and foo3.Value, output should be false (2013-03-19 16:00 < 2013-03-19 15:00)
            Debug.Assert(false == Evaluate(DateTime.Parse("2013-03-19 15:00"), new Foo 
                        { 
                            Value = "2013-03-19 16:00", 
                            OperatorType = OperatorTypes.Less, 
                            ValueType = ValueTypes.Date 
                        }));
        }
    }

    public enum OperatorTypes : uint
    {
        Equal = 1,
        Greater = 2,
        GreaterOrEqual = 3,
        Less = 4,
        LessOrEqual = 5
    }

    public enum ValueTypes : uint
    {
        None = 0,
        Integer = 1,
        Long = 2,
        Numeric = 3,
        Date = 4,
        Text = 5,
        Bool = 6
    }

    class Foo
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public ValueTypes ValueType { get; set; }
        public OperatorTypes OperatorType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This could do with a lot of improvement (better type checking, CultureInfo awareness and error handling). But, it's a start

Comment: I got RuntimeBinderException: Operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'object', which similar to the situation I faced today, because object cannot compare to value type.

Comment: Aha. Better make it dynamic too then. Editing.

Comment: right, it works now, it's little bit evil because it's exploiting dynamic, but neat enough and get the job done.

Comment: @James It beats writing basically the same yourself, so I'm not sure whether it is really evil here. If anything, you'll have less opportunity to write your own bugs and you get consistent error information if something fails at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Compare<double>("123.1", 125.3, (a, b) => a > b));
        Console.WriteLine(Compare<DateTime>("19/03/2013", DateTime.Now, (a, b) => a == b));
    }

    private static bool Compare<T>(string valueAsString, T valueToComapare, Func<T,T,bool> check)
    {
        var asObject = (T)Convert.ChangeType(valueAsString, typeof(T));

        if (asObject != null)
        {
            return check(asObject, valueToComapare);
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know `Convert.ChangeType` existed.

Comment: @Yaugen Vlasau, your code no doubt works but it is not generalized to validate against ValueType. Addtional code is required.